# Disassemble MS-DOS 2.0 boot sector

Tags: ida, dos

I try disassemble boot sector for floppy 360K MS-DOS 2.0. There is code:

```
;bios parameter block here

seg000:001F                 db    0
seg000:0020                 db  0Ah
seg000:0021                 db 0DFh
seg000:0022                 db    2
seg000:0023                 db  25h ; %
seg000:0024                 db    2
seg000:0025                 db    9
seg000:0026                 db  2Ah ; *
seg000:0027                 db 0FFh
seg000:0028                 db  50h ; P
seg000:0029                 db 0F6h ; ¡
seg000:002A                 db    0
seg000:002B                 db    2
seg000:002C ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
seg000:002C
seg000:002C reboot:                                 ; CODE XREF: seg000:loc_77j
seg000:002C                 int     19h             ; DISK BOOT
seg000:002C                                         ; causes reboot of disk system
seg000:002E
seg000:002E msdos_main:                             ; CODE XREF: seg000:0000j
seg000:002E                 cli
seg000:002F                 xor     ax, ax
seg000:0031                 mov     ss, ax
seg000:0033                 mov     sp, 7C00h
seg000:0036                 mov     ds, ax
seg000:0038                 mov     word ptr ds:loc_79+1, ax
seg000:003B                 mov     word ptr ds:loc_77+1, 7C21h ; DATA XREF: print_msg+Br
seg000:0041                 sti
seg000:0042                 int     13h
```

```
seg000:0074                 call    read_root_dir_into_memory
seg000:0077
seg000:0077 loc_77:                                 ; DATA XREF: seg000:003Bw
seg000:0077                 jb      short reboot
seg000:0079
seg000:0079 loc_79:                                 ; DATA XREF: seg000:0038w
seg000:0079                 mov     ax, ds:7C13h    ; StartUserData
seg000:007C                 mov     ds:7D7Eh, ax    ; StartUserDataVal
seg000:007F                 mov     ax, 70h ; 'p'   ; location 0h:0700h is for read IBMBIO.COM for MS-DOS
seg000:0082                 mov     es, ax
```

I dont understand this lines:

```
seg000:0038                 mov     word ptr ds:loc_79+1, ax
seg000:003B                 mov     word ptr ds:loc_77+1, 7C21h ; DATA XREF: print_msg+Br
```

What is this? This lines break code seems.

UPD.

I took this code:

```
seg000:0038                 mov     word ptr ds:loc_79+1, ax
seg000:003B                 mov     word ptr ds:loc_77+1, 7C21h ; DATA XREF: print_msg+Br
```

In hex view:

```
A3 7A 00 C7 06 78 00 21 7C
```

Using C++ write binary, then disassemble it, result is:

```
seg000:0000                 mov     ds:7Ah, ax
seg000:0003                 mov     word ptr ds:78h, 7C21h
```

And offset in memory 0h:78h seems is disk parameter table, and what is ds:7Ah I dont know.

Answer (score 1):

Interrupt vector table on 8086 is a vector that consists of 256 total interrupts placed at first 1 kb of memory from 0000h to 03ffh, where each vector consists of segment and offset as a jump table to memory address. So, 78h >> 2 = 1Eh and 7Ah >> 2 = 1Eh . Int 1E is not an interrupt, but a far pointer to the diskette base table

Comment: 78h >> 2 = 1Eh and 7Ah >> 2 = 1Eh you mean shift right on 2 bits?

Comment: Each interrupt vector contains segment and offset - total 4 bytes. 78h >> 2 == 78h / 4, same with 7Ah . I's segment and offset of diskette base table.

Comment: Can you explain me difference - Bios Parameter Block in boot sector vs Diskette Parameter Table. Bios Parameter Block need describes  disk volume (for exmple floppy disk 1440 KB). And Diskette Parameter Table describes itself disk drive device. I.e. one is for floppy diskette, second for device that reading this diskette. Am I right understood?

Comment: Correct. **BPB** describes the physical layout of a disk volume as bytes per sector, sectors per cluster, num of FAT, etc. **DPT** contains initialization parameters as clock ticks until motor off, FM or MFM Mode, gap length when formatting (5,25" or 3,5"), etc.

Comment: I saw such comment, in asm code of boot sector, against line with changes "head settle time" - comment is: ; Set the head settle time to 15ms because we don't have room ; to do a disk retry and then set sectors per from the value ; in the BPB - what this comment means?

Comment: Is it IDA's auto-generanted comment or you manage to find some source code?

Comment: I found this comment in source code of OS against line where was made changes of parameter "head settle time". It was not IDA auto-generated. mov BYTE PTR [DI-2], 0fh ; Head settle time - where DI is pointing to end DPT.

Comment: Matches this  [information](https://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_1e.html) , but no idea about 15 milliseconds value.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood this code correctly. :)

These instructions move data into memory locations.
So basically if code exists there, it will be overriden and instructions will change their meaning.

1. `seg000:0038 A3 7A 00      mov word ptr ds:loc_79+1, ax`

   It means move `ax = 0000` to address `ds:loc_79+1`. Memory cells `7A` and `7B` now contain value `00`.
   And if You read bytes starting from address `0079` instruction

   `seg000:0079 A1 13 7C     mov ax, ds:7C13h`

   will change to `mov ax, ds:0000h (A1 00 00)`

   Same thing happens to second instruction.
2. `seg000:003B C7 06 78 00 21 7C         mov word ptr ds:loc_77+1, 7C21h`

   Under address `0077` there is `jb short reboot`
   According to intel manual this is short conditional jump, so this is 2 byte instruction
   `72 cb | JB rel8 | D | Valid | Valid | Jump short if below (CF=1)`

   Byte `72` stay intact because code writes word `7C21` to address `78` and the trick is that
   byte `0079` which previously contain value `A1` (see point 1), will be changed to `7C`

   So now memory will look like:

```
    77 78 79 7A 7B 
    72 21 7C 00 00 

    seg000:0077 loc_77:     
    seg000:0077                 jb/jnae 21 ; (jump 21h bytes forward)
    seg000:0079
    seg000:0079 loc_79:                    
    seg000:0079                 jl/jnge 00 ; (execute next instruction)
```

```
    seg000:002C reboot:                                 ; CODE XREF: seg000:loc_77j
    seg000:002C CD 19               int     19h             ; DISK BOOT
    seg000:002C                                         ; causes reboot of disk system
    seg000:002E
    seg000:002E msdos_main:                             ; CODE XREF: seg000:0000j
    seg000:002E FA                  cli
    seg000:002F 31 C0               xor     ax, ax
    seg000:0031 8E D0               mov     ss, ax
    seg000:0033 BC 00 7C            mov     sp, 7C00h
    seg000:0036 8E D8               mov     ds, ax
    seg000:0038 A3 7A 00            mov     word ptr ds:loc_79+1, ax
    seg000:003B C7 06 78 00 21 7C   mov     word ptr ds:loc_77+1, 7C21h ; DATA XREF: print_msg+Br
    seg000:0041 FB                  sti
    seg000:0042 CD 13               int     13h
```

I hope I didn't mess anything... and this is mbr loaded to 0:7C00 btw.